# How to add text on top of vrtk radial button?

Tags: unity3d, virtual-reality

I want to create a dynamic radial menu using vrtk radial menu script. I can initialize the button dynamically but can't add any text to them. The text element that I set as their child is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.
Just needed to tweek the arc prefab a bit.
Added a 3d TextMeshPro as child of arc, with scale 25,25,1.
Then changed the allignment a bit. It worked like a charm.